# How to Create an OpenGL context in Python

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I am using pygame and pyopengl, and am trying to get glGenTextures(1,img) to return 1. I have checked that 'myPixelArt.bmp' has power-of-2 dimensions. My script starts with:

```
import pygame, OpenGL, math, numpy
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.WGL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from PIL import Image
from ctypes import *

img = Image.open('myPixelArt.bmp')
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

hdc=windll.user32.GetDC(1)
print hdc

hglrc=wglCreateContext(hdc)
wglMakeCurrent(hdc,hglrc)
im=glGenTextures(1,img)
print im
```

But this prints out 0 for hdc and 0 for im.

What argument should I use for windll.user32.GetDC to create a display context and hopefully get glGenTextures to return 1?

Comment: Not much experience with pygame, but most windowing systems won't let you create a context until you've initialised the window system and created some kind of top level window. I suggest creating a blank window first and trying again

Answer (score 0):

Try to first create a window!

```python
import pygame, OpenGL, math, numpy
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.WGL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from PIL import Image
from ctypes import *

size=(800,600)
pygame.display.set_mode(size,pygame.OPENGL|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

img = Image.open('myPixelArt.bmp')
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

hdc=windll.user32.GetDC(1)
print hdc

hglrc=wglCreateContext(hdc)
wglMakeCurrent(hdc,hglrc)
im=glGenTextures(1,img)
print im
```

Becouse Pygame creates an OpenGL-context along with the window.